# Gradle can't resolve my dependencies if not provided in a certain format

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, artifactory

I can't pull any dependencies from my Artifactory repository, if they're in a certain format. However maven manages to pull all those dependencies without any problems regardless of the format.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find eu.****:cloudnet-bridge:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.****.dev:443/artifactory/****-repo/eu/****/cloudnet-bridge/1.0.0/cloudnet-bridge-1.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.****.dev:443/artifactory/****-repo/eu.****/cloudnet-bridge/ivy-1.0.0.xml
     Required by:
         project :
```

This is the error I am getting in IntelliJ (2020.1.2 Community Edition) using gradle (6.5).

[This is the folder structure for a non-working dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbG5X.png) (the jar is directly placed in the folder)

[This is the folder structure for a working dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrNpy.png) (the jar is inside a version folder along with a valid POM; the artifactory auto-generated one does NOT work here! There also is a xml file in the dependency's root folder containing some information about the version etc.)

Now my question is whether or not I can fix this issue.

Comment: this might help you: 
 https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#maven_or_ivy_repositories_are_no_longer_queried_for_artifacts_without_metadata_by_default

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the lack of a `.pom` is the problem.

By default, Gradle 6 can't find dependencies unless they have metadata.  This is a change from Gradle 5 behaviour.  You can customise it by adding a `metadataSources` block to your repository declaration, like this:

```kotlin
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://repo.****.dev:443/artifactory/****-repo")
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
```

This means, "Look for the `.pom` first, but if there is no `.pom`, look for the `.jar`."

You might also want to add `gradleMetadata()` if the repo contains any.